# Running Windows 10 on an i3-3110M processor, any way to reduce OS processing needs for this chip?

Tags: windows-10, intel-core-i3, ivy-bridge, low-power

A am working on a video monitoring system that will be operating at a remote site using solar power. We are using older laptops running Ivy Bridge processors and Windows 10. We would like to one of the i3 processors to reduce power consumption. While video storage functions as expected using the i3, the GUI is laggy. Is there anything I can do to tweak the Windows operating system to reduce demand on the processor? Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Just to be clear, two items:

1.) The location where this system will be deployed is power limited due to nearly mountains and trees which are non-optimal for solar power. Simply upgrading to a faster processor is not practical.

2.) In a test set-up here in the lab, the i3-3110M performs adequately. We are interested the possibility of taking this a step further and testing one of the low power i3 processors. These are the i3-3220T, i3-3240T, and i3-3250T.

There are a number of single board computers capable of running Win10. I'd be interested in if there were any OS adjustments to allow it to function within limitations of the SBC. Furthermore, it is relevant to note that there will be no human interface to this system for extended periods (weeks) while video data is collected and uploaded. The i3-3000 appears to have no problem doing this. Possibly the low power i3 processors will be capable of adequate video handling as well, with the only limitation being infrequent suboptimal human interface.

Comment: Since Ivy Bridge is discontinued, and there are newer CPUs from Intel that are massively more efficient now, I would recommend that you question the use of these laptops entirely. Something newer will be both faster and more power efficient than an Ivy Bridge laptop.

Comment: "Is there anything I can do to tweak the Windows operating system to reduce demand on the processor?" - You could make the same kind of tweaks that was done to create Tiny11. [Here](https://www.neowin.net/news/tiny10-version-2303-brings-modern-lightweight-and-serviceable-windows-10-to-old-pcs/) is one such project that does that.

Answer (score 2):

The CPU that you have is not meant for the load you are giving it.

(1) There are no tweaks (AFIK) for Windows to reduce overload on an underpowered CPU.

(2) I am sure you know that you need a faster computer.

Comment: Windows 10 works just fine on Ivy Bridge processors. The problem likely is connected to a lack of system memory and the fact it’s a low end mobile processor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The laptop in use with the i3-3110M processor has the maximum of 16gb of RAM installed.

Comment: @portsample - 16GB is more than enough memory for Windows 10.